# Word wrap and full justify text so that each line has the same length

Tags: java, word-wrap, justify

I am trying to create a class HW2 using the prettyPrint method. I am trying to do a word wrap and full justify text so that each line has the same length (using System.out.println). I am trying to get something to look like this:

```
HW2.prettyPrint("This homework is demonstrating how word processors make the text in a document line up so neatly.", 25)
```

```
This     homework      is
demonstrating  how   word
processors make the  text
in a document line up  so
neatly.
```

And this is my code that is not working - any ideas on how to fix?

```
  public static void prettyPrint(String s, int x) {
    int numberWords = countWords(s);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
      if(i <= x){
        padString(s, x);
        builder.append(s.charAt(i));
      }
      if(i == x){
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
    System.out.println();

    // use CountWords, separate words into an array, then concatenate every line and use padString to output the correct length

    // print one line first, then move on to another
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into the module operator (`%`)

Comment: Were the two comments near the bottom written by your teacher? You should follow the algorithm outlined there. You have not.

Comment: The comments at the bottom were mine - but I was not sure how to implement there